# SSIS Derived column?

Tags: ssis

Need have the expression to get the last year same month of the getdate() in derived column

I am trying with

```
(DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("yyyy",GETDATE()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("mm",GETDATE()),2)
```

current result 201408

expected result 201308

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(DT_STR,4,1252)(DATEPART("yyyy",GETDATE()) - 1) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("mm",GETDATE()),2)
```

The -1 in the expression for the year part will return the previous year, without affecting computations for getting the month part.